# Obtaining the generelized acceleration from the kinetic energy

Tags: energy, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, acceleration, coordinate-systems

I have the kinetic equation $T=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{\alpha=1}^N v_{\alpha}^2 $. So we have $T=(q,\dot q,t)$. From that, it is written that we get the generelized acceleration:

[image]

Of course, I know that the first term is the momentum, which I write above it. But I am trying to make sense of the second term. This is part of the theory of Lagrangian, not an example.
Thank you in advance for your help.